# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and gnutls_handshake() failed - SSL/HTTPS are failing [Ubuntu Server 18.04]

Tags: git, ssl, curl, https, ubuntu-18.04

I hope somebody can help me!  Any SSL/HTTPS calls using any method or command line doesn't work.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 as a Subsystem in Windows 10. My issue only started yesterday as I know SSL/HTTPS was working the other day. I updated Ubuntu via "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" yesterday and I think it somehow broke the SSL/HTTPS access.

The issue is I can't open any HTTPS links, using any command line (ex: curl, wget, git). I keep getting errors.

[curl https://www.microsoft.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTsvT.png)

[curl https://www.google.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7rXR.png)

[trying to clone in github using https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9lBR.png)

[tried also via WGET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECkcz.png)

I don't know what is happening here, and I've tried searching for solution but I have not found any yet.

Please HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to your anti-virus software. Some anti-virus software wants to man-in-the-middle connections to "secure" your data and will block connections it cannot insert itself into. Since most Windows anti-virus software can't handle the Linux ELF executables, your connection fails.

Generally you want to remove such anti-virus software completely (disabling it may not be enough) and just stick with Windows Defender.

Comment: I can say that this is not this is not due to any Anti-Virus.  I've been using anti-virus since before I installed the windows subsystem. And the Ubuntu Server has been working fine for months already.

It only started a few days ago, HTTPS/SSL calls even through python doesn't work.

I've got 2 additional Unbuntu serververs but via virtual machines which is still working fine. No issues with HTTPS/SSL calls.

I've also tried via some commands using the Windows 10 PowerShell and also no issues using HTTPS/SSL.
It's only on the Ubuntu Server under the Windows Subsystem that isn't working

Comment: Ok... I take back my comment.  I guess @brian was right about the anti-virus.. somehow it screwed the HTTPS firewall, which only affects the LInux Subsystem.

Pausing the Anti-Virus didn't work. But exiting it, did fix the issue.

By the way, I'm using Kaspersky Free.

Comment: This is actually a known problem with Kaspersky. It apparently does bad things to WSL, and pausing it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @brian.. Kaspersky says they will patch it, but I doubt this will ever go away soon

Comment: By the way, I want to Upvote your answer but I don't have enough reps yet.. sorry @brian